# Periodogram and frequency

Tags: data, fourier-analysis, time-series, signal-processing

On the `x` axis of periodogram, one should have either a period or frequency. What frequency is used in `Periodogram` --- angular or frequency in "Hz"?

No matter what data I feed it, it keeps showing the `x` axis from `[0,0.5]`. Why? Or more importantly, I do want real frequencies so that I have an idea what to filter out.

Since `Periodogram` accepts only 1-Dimensional lists, it cannot know anything about a frequency and assumes that the data are spaced 1 second apart. It has the option of `SampleRate` but it only accepts integer values. How do I get around it (what if my data are spaced 0.7 seconds apart?)?

So how do I display "real" frequencies in the data using `Periodogram`?

Note, to have some example, I am playing with this:

```
dataclean = Table[Sin[n], {n, 0, 20, 0.01}];
Periodogram[dataclean, PlotRange -> All, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Absolute"]
```

The periodogram makes no sense at all. $\sin(x)$ has a period of $2\pi$. That means that the angular frequency is 1 and the normal frequency is $\sim 0.16$. Additionally, its fourier series is just $\sin(x)$. But in this case the frequency peak position depends on the length of the list and its division. Also note that using `SampleRate` does not affect the peak position at all. I know it is my mistake of misunderstanding the `Periodogram` but I am at loss at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

In order to get things visible you have to adapt the plot range. Try eg

```
dataclean = Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] n] + 1/3 Sin[6 \[Pi] n], {n, 0, 20, 0.01}];

ListPlot[Take[dataclean, 200]]

Periodogram[dataclean, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.4}, All}, ScalingFunctions -> "Absolute"]
```